# Swift. URL returning nil

Tags: swift, url, fatal-error, uiapplication

I am trying to open a website in my app, but for some reason one line keeps returning nil, heres my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(element.Name)")!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

It's the first line (`let url = URL...`) that keeps on returning this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Check `element.Name`. If it's an optional String Interpolation can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't force unwrap it with (!). When you use (!) and the value of the variable is nil, your program crashes and you get that error. Instead, you want to safely unwrap the optional with either a "guard let" or an "if let" statement.

```
guard let name = element.Name as? String else {
    print("something went wrong, element.Name can not be cast to String")
    return
}

if let url = URL(string: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(name)") {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
} else {
    print("could not open url, it was nil")
}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you may have an issue with element.Name. So I would check to see if that's an optional next if you're still having issues.

**Update**

I added a possible way to check the element.Name property to see if you can cast it as a String and create the desired url you're looking to create. You can see the code above the code I previously posted.

Comment: This only solves the error, not the cause of the error. I'm sure the goal is to end up with a valid URL.

Comment: can you please explain further? If he/she is not getting a valid url from this, then I would look next at the element.Name property.

Comment: The OP want to create a URL using `element.Name`. As is, that is causing the URL to be `nil` resulting in a crash. Your answer simply prevents the crash but it doesn't solve the issue of creating the URL as desired.

Comment: It solves the error that was given in the question. I agree with you that it doesn't give a full solution for creating a url from element.Name, but I don't know what more I can do without knowing more information about element.Name.

Comment: @rmaddy I added an additional check on element.Name to give a complete solution. Hopefully, this will be satisfactory. If not, I would love your guidance on how it can be improved.

Comment: The likely issue is that `element.Name` contains characters that need to be escaped such as spaces or other special characters.

Comment: ahh, ok. That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thank you, it works now! No errors and it loads the website perfectly

Answer (score 27):

> I think this will help.
>    Your element.name may contain space between words so addingPercentEncoding make PercentEncoding string.

```
let txtAppend = (element.Name).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(txtAppend!)"
let openUrl = NSURL(string: url)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(openUrl as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(openUrl as! URL)
}
```

Comment: Incorrect allowed characters.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 4 version for this fix:

```
str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: Incorrect allowed characters.

Answer (score 12):

This will definitely works for you. The problem is occurring due to space in between your string URL. To fix this use

```
let imagePath = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arcti cha re.png"

let urlString = imagePath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) //This will fill the spaces with the %20

let url = URL(string: urlString) //This will never return nil
```

Comment: Incorrect allowed characters.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that your URL is not properly formated after adding the `element.Name` .
so just use the function

```swift
addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

It's just surprising that the URL constructor doesn't take the URL format into consideration

Comment: This is wrong. The idea is good but this is not how you correctly encoded URL query. This won't correctly encode chars like `?`, `&` or `+`.

Answer (score 1):

it may be an encoding issue.
have you tried

```
let str = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(element.Name)"
let encodedStr = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCha‌​racterSet.URLQueryAl‌​lowedCharacterSet()
```

Answer (score 1):

It may contain Zero-width-space, as the name suggests, it is a Unicode character, invisible to the naked eye

```
extension String {
    func replacePattern(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") -> String {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
            let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.count)
            return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch {
            return self
        }
    }
    
    var fixZeroWidthSpace: String {
        addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)?.replacePattern(pattern: "%E2%80%8B", replaceWith: "") ?? ""
    }
}

let url = urlString.fixZeroWidthSpace
```

Answer (score 0):

URLComponents is meant to dodge the hell of manual escaping of url components (for each different rules apply)

```
public func configure()
{
    if var urc = URLComponents(string: "https://fake/") {
        urc.host = your real hostname with whatever characters are not allowed in hostname
        ... same deal for other url components
        YourScope.baseUrlPath = urc.url?.absoluteString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure it would help your specific situation, but I had a similar set of symptoms and the cause(after so much frustration) was just blank spaces in the long url with an  API key and stuff. As suggested by “@workingdog support Ukraine” I added in % in the blanks and it worked. (Note: it was on a date/time part of a long api url the % was inserted into my code so idk if it applies to dates specifically or the entire url)
Anyway this might help someone else.
Be blessed