# WKWebView crashing with certain queries (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm developing a tinderlike swipe app for babynames. I've created a method that, when you click a button besides one of your favorite names, it pops up a window (A UIViewController with a WKWebView) that shows a google search with the meaning of this particular name.

The problem is that with some names, the app crashes because the URL returns nil. I don't understand what's happening, because other names are working just fine. I've found out it happens with Scandinavian names like "OddVeig" and "OddLaug" .

Below is my UIViewController class that pops up with the search result (I've put all the initializing code in the layoutSubViews(), because I had some trouble in iOS 12, where the WKWebView wouldn't resize properly if I put it in the viewDidLoad() ) :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webContainer: UIView!
    var webView : WKWebView!
    var query : String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webContainer.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.alpha = 0.9
        
        webView.frame = self.view.frame
        webView.layer.position.y += 20
        let slideDownImage = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        slideDownImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "slideIconWhite"), for: .normal)
        slideDownImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        if let n = query {
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=\(n)")! // Causing error: Found nil
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        }
        webContainer.addSubview(slideDownImage)
        slideDownImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.webView.frame.size.width, height: 20)
        slideDownImage.backgroundColor = .gray
        slideDownImage.alpha = 0.7
        slideDownImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slideDown), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func slideDown() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

I use a segue in the FavoritesViewController class like this :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "favoritesToWeb" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! WebViewController
        destination.query = "\(searchName)+\(NSLocalizedString("meaning", comment: "meaning"))"
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Patrick

Comment: You can not add such code inside the viewDidLayoutSubviews method. Just manage and set the frame inside the viewDidLayoutSubviews method else other code add in to the viewDidLoad.

Comment: What's the actual URL that causes the app to crash?  And why are you force-unwrapping the url?

Comment: The following is wrong.  destination.query = "\(searchName)+\(NSLocalizedString("meaning", comment: "meaning"))"

Comment: destination.query = searchName + "+" + NSLocalizedString("meaning", comment: "meaning")

Comment: @RajaKishan Thanks. I've edited it in my code, so that didLayoutSubviews only contains changes to the frame.

Comment: @ElTomato The url should be : "https://www.google.com/search?q=Oddveig+meaning", but is return nil. It has to do something with the url in combination with the particular name. "q=Odd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query`  variable need to be percentage encoded, I guess this must be crashing while you have whitespace characters in query string. use `addingPercentEncoding` for adding percentage encoding to query string.

Reference to API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding

Related Question:
[Swift. URL returning nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368389/swift-url-returning-nil)

Comment: Omg that's it thanks :) I'm reading all the names from a .txt file and apparently some names had whitespaces at the end, which I couldn't see. Perfect this fixed it!